Multipart data isn't present in the request when calling formData for HttpRequestBuilder
I've tried using the following code, but the results are not as expected. The FormData is missing from the final request.
Is something wrong with how I'm building the HttpRequestBuilder?
val client = HttpClient()
val request = HttpRequestBuilder().apply {
    url("https://httpbin.org/post")
    method = HttpMethod.Post
    formData {
        append("objectType", "2")
    }
}
val response = client.request(request)


The problem is that the formData is a pure function that doesn't mutate a HttpRequestBuilder but only returns a list of PartData objects. To send the multipart/form-data request, instantiate the MultiPartFormDataContent class by supplying a list of PartData created by the formData function and pass that instance to the setBody method:
val request = HttpRequestBuilder().apply {
    url("https://httpbin.org/post")
    method = HttpMethod.Post
    setBody(
        MultiPartFormDataContent(
            formData {
                append("objectType", "2")
            }
        )
    )
}

